# Excel 2007 - formula to display last updated cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have 6 cells, `A1-A6` in *Sheet1*.

`A1,A3,& A5` contain numbers 1-3

`A2,A4,& A6` contain the date the numbers changed.

`A1 & A2` will be filled first. I want to display both cells in *Sheet2* in `B1 & B2`.

When `A3 & A4` are filled, I want to replace the contents of `B1 & B2` with the new data.

Similarly, when `A5 & A6` are filled I want to replace the contents of `B1 & B2` with the new data.

I need to keep all the data in *Sheet1* but only want the latest data displayed in *Sheet2*.

Is there a formula that can do this as I need it automatically?  I am unable to use VBA or macros to do this.

Answer (score 0):

A) It's usually good form to show what you've tried

B) this would have probably been better posted on [Stack Overflow.SE](http://stackoverflow.com)

I have set up Column A with these 6 rows:

```
1
2/1/2015
2
2/14/2015
3
3/1/2015
```

Based on that, I put these formulas in other cells on the same sheet

```
'return the odd numbered row (1, 2 or 3)
=INDEX($A$1:$A$6,MATCH(MAX($A$2,$A$4,$A$6),$A$1:$A$6,0)-1)
'return the associated date
=INDEX($A$1:$A$6,MATCH(MAX($A$2,$A$4,$A$6),$A$1:$A$6,0))
```

You'll need to change the cell references to point to the appropriate sheet.

Comment: (A) I agree. (B) No, Excel questions that can be answered without VBA are on-topic on Super User; see [Please don't vote to close Excel questions as off-topic](http://meta.superuser.com/q/9099). Even questions that require limited VBA are generally allowed. In case of a gray area, the general rule is that a question belongs on whatever site the asker chooses to put it on.

Comment: (B) Roger that, @Scott.

Answer (score 0):

In *Sheet2* cell **B1** enter:

```
=CHOOSE(1+COUNT(Sheet1!A1:A6)/2,"",Sheet1!A1,Sheet1!A3,Sheet1!A5)
```

and in cell **B2** enter:

```
=CHOOSE(1+COUNT(Sheet1!A1:A6)/2,"",Sheet1!A2,Sheet1!A4,Sheet1!A6)
```

These formulas assume you are filling *Sheet1* in pairs and in the order indicated.